# How can I store a time value, specifically only hour and minute in Firebase?

Tags: json, firebase, time, firebase-realtime-database

I don't need this time associated with any date. In fact, I don't want it associated with a specific date. It's more so associated with a generic day of the week. Monday, Saturday, etc.

For example, your local coffee shop sets their hours for Monday based on the fact that it is a Monday. Not based on it being May 22, 2017 or May 29, 2017, etc.

I could do something like...

```
"Local Coffee Shoppe": 
{
    "availability": 
    {
        "monday":
        {
            "start":
            {
                "hour": 7,
                "minute": 30
            },
            "end":
            {
                "hour": 21,
                "minute": 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This would mean the Local Coffee Shoppe is open Mondays from 7:30am to 9:00pm.

Is this the best way to achieve this? All times would be stored in UTC for example, with conversion happening client side.

EDIT1: Just realized there is a hole in this approach. It doesn't cover establishments that are open past midnight. To combat this, maybe each day just stores "start" and then "duration"...

```
    "monday":
    {
        "start":
        {
            "hour": 7,
            "minute": 30
        },
        "duration":
        {
            "hour": 13,
            "minute": 30
        }
    }
```

So it is open for 13 hours and 30 minutes past 7:30am. I.E. 9:00pm.

Comment: Are you looking for a SQL solution or something else?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No just essentially the best way to do it. I suppose I could store an entire date and then just strip out the hour and minute, but that seems ambiguous and confusing. Just wondering if this is the best course.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen actually I just realized there is a hole in this approach. It wouldn't work for establishments that stay open past 12am

Comment: From what I understand, Firebase is based off an old version of Postgres.  Assuming there is a time type, you could store those points in time using that.  Then, e.g. add them to timestamps to get an actual timestamp for the opening date.

Comment: did you ever end up with a solution to this problem?

Answer (score -3):

I would recommend just storing timestamps and extracting as you suggested, that would be a good approach, this would also allow you to already have the code to expand your use case if you want.